# Lambda Event Handler in C# - VB.NET Equivalent

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, winforms

I need to convert the following code from C# to VB.NET.

```
lnkSynEvent.Click += 
         new EventHandler((s,e)=>lnkSynEvent_Click(s, e, your_parameter));
```

Here lnkSynEvent is the id of button. Any Help is appreciated.

Comment: http://converter.telerik.com/#

Comment: @Narek Arzumanyan. I had tried that telerik converter already but when i use that code in visual studio it throws error at compile time

Comment: @vinunatesh Please share your code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can be used like this:

```
AddHandler lnkSynEvent.Click , Sub(s, ea) lnkSynEvent_Click(s, ea, your_parameter)
```

Or this:

```
AddHandler lnkSynEvent.Click , Sub(s, ea)
                                   lnkSynEvent_Click(s, ea, your_parameter)
                               End Sub
```

**Note**

- Pay attention, you should have a `lnkSynEvent_Click` accepting 3 parameters of consistent types which you are trying to pass to it.
- Usually you can trust the out put of online code converters, but you should have enough knowledge and know syntax yourself enough to be able to change some part of converted codes.
- For more description and example take a look at [Lambda Expressions (Visual Basic)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb531253.aspx).

Comment: Thanks for your solution. It Works fine

Answer (score 0):

```
lnkSynEvent.Click += New EventHandler(Function(s, e) lnkSynEvent_Click(s, e, your_parameter))
```

Answer (score 0):

You get online code converter which can help you to convert C# to VB.

> http://converter.telerik.com/

```
lnkSynEvent.Click += New EventHandler(Function(s, e) lnkSynEvent_Click(s, e, your_parameter))
```

Comment: This isn't an answer to OP, also, if you paste the exact C# line they are wanting converted, the telerik converter returns an error as lnkSynEvent.Click is not implemented and therefore, the converter doesn't know what to do with it.  A more helpful answer would be to include what OP could have done to get such a line to convert properly using the provided converter. (ex. replace lnksynevent.click with something else, etc)